# Send a pandas dataframe to slack

Tags: python, pandas, slack

I am trying to send a pandas dataframe on a channel on slack using the following small script:

```
import requests
URL = 'XXXXXX'

response = requests.post(
        URL, data={dataframe}
    )
```

But when I do that I have the following error message: `'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`! I also tried to send it as a json but then it is unreadable for the users. Any idea on how to do this properly? thanks!

My dataframe looks at follow:

```
    Bot instance    Current Potential profit    Potential Profit 24h ago    Change last 24h Volume 24h  Volume Market
    0   Biki - TECUSDT  21.69386074 USDT    21.60458081 USDT    0.08927993 USDT 0.84554375 USDT 28577.2565559176490500
    1   Binance - XEMBTC    -3.55974813 BTC -3.55514961 BTC -0.00459852 BTC 11.31867593 BTC 924.7716585800000000
    2   Binance - XEM/ETH   -15.38320177 ETH    -15.32533185 ETH    -0.05786992 ETH 35.44241506 ETH 1273.2456803600000000
    3   bitfinex ant/btc    1.64774952 BTC  1.65615563 BTC  -0.00840611 BTC 0.01056552 BTC  5.2507294117379079
    4   Bitfinex ANT/ETH    -15.93635190 ETH    -15.60342681 ETH    -0.33292509 ETH 0.00000000 ETH  99.3832923859608600
```

And when I send it to slack as a json it looks like this:

> {"Bot instance":{"0":"Biki - TECUSDT","1":"Binance - XEMBTC","2":"Binance - XEM/ETH","3":"bitfinex ant/btc","4":"Bitfinex ANT/ETH","5":"Bitfinex ANT/USD","6":"Bitfinex ODE/BTC","7":"Bitfinex ODE/USD","8":"Bitfinex - RIFBTC","9":"Bitfinex - RIFUSD","10":"Bitfinex - VLD/USD","11":"Bittrex ANT/BTC","12":"Bittrex ANT/ETH","13":"Bittrex - GBYTEBTC","14":"Bitvavo - ANT/EUR","15":"Coinall - RIFBTC","16":"Coindeal - PHT/ETH","17":"Coinmetro - PRQEUR","18":"Hitbtc ANTBTC","19":"Hitbtc - PLBTBTC","20":"Hitbtc - PLBTETH","21":"Hitbtc - PLR/BTC","22":"Hitbtc - PLR/ETH","23":"Hitbtc - PLR/USDT","24":"Kucoin - RIFBTC","25":"LGO - LGOUSD","26":"Liquid - RIFUSD","27":"Livecoin - PLBTBTC","28":"Livecoin - PLBTETH","29":"Livecoin - PLBTUSD","30":"Nash - ANTBTC","31":"Poloniex - PRQUSDT","32":"P2PB2B - ANTBTC"},"Current Potential profit":{"0":"21.69386074 USDT","1":"-3.55974813 BTC","2":"-15.38320177 ETH","3":"1.64774952 BTC","4":"-15.93635190 ETH","5":"-22533.4891602 USD","6":null,"7":"-163.0524

Which is not readable for users

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html) to encode your data as string. That should be somewhat readable in Slack.

```
response = requests.post(
    URL,
    data={'<payload_key>': dataframe.to_markdown()}
)
```

`to_markdown` gives a string like this:

```
|    | index             | Bot instance     | Current Potential profit   | Potential Profit 24h ago   | Change last 24h Volume   |   24h  Volume Market |
|---:|:------------------|:-----------------|:---------------------------|:---------------------------|:-------------------------|---------------------:|
|  0 | Biki - TECUSDT    | 21.69386074 USDT | 21.60458081 USDT           | 0.08927993 USDT            | 0.84554375 USDT          |          28577.3     |
|  1 | Binance - XEMBTC  | -3.55974813 BTC  | -3.55514961 BTC            | -0.00459852 BTC            | 11.31867593 BTC          |            924.772   |
|  2 | Binance - XEM/ETH | -15.38320177 ETH | -15.32533185 ETH           | -0.05786992 ETH            | 35.44241506 ETH          |           1273.25    |
|  3 | bitfinex ant/btc  | 1.64774952 BTC   | 1.65615563 BTC             | -0.00840611 BTC            | 0.01056552 BTC           |              5.25073 |
|  4 | Bitfinex ANT/ETH  | -15.93635190 ETH | -15.60342681 ETH           | -0.33292509 ETH             | 0.00000000 ETH           |             99.3833  |
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I have `<Response [400]>` , any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Your 'data' should be an encoded string, e.g.

```
message = 'string'
data = message.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but then I have the following message: `invalid payload` , I tired to google it but could not find a straightforward answer

Comment: Slack doesn't like what you send to it, assuming your URL is a webhook, try this:

    `message = 'string'
    slack_message = {
        'username': username,
        'channel': slack_channel,
        'text': message
    }
    response = requests.post(
        URL, data=json.dumps(slack_message).encode('utf-8')
    )`

Comment: so something like the following? `slack_message = { 'username': 'Viktor Weinand', 'channel': '@viktor', 'text': message }
data = slack_message.encode('utf-8')

response = requests.post(
        URL, data={data}
    ) `

Comment: Because then I have `dict` object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: without `encode('utf-8')` I have the same error, `invalid payload`

Comment: Thats correct, thats why you have to convert dict to string with json.dumps and then encode. And slack channel should be id, not a name, for direct message like "C1H9RESGL".

Comment: That's exactly my problem when I convert the dict to string then it is unreadable on slack, it gives me the following: `{"Bot instance":{"0":"Biki - TECUSDT","1":"Binance - XEMBTC","2":"Binance - XEM\/ETH","3":"bitfinex ant\/btc","4":"Bitfinex ANT\/ETH","5":"Bitfinex ANT\/USD","6":"Bitfinex ODE\/BTC","7":"Bitfinex ODE\/USD","8":"Bitfinex - RIFBTC",1}`

Comment: I would recommend to ask another question, i.e. how to format slack message instead. You can dig in here but my take your intention is never going to look right on different screens, let alone phones.
https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting

Answer (score 0):

After testing this should work:

> **for private channel**: make sure your bot has access to your channel you are trying to send the message to. If they are not in it, **add** the bot to the channel.

```py
import pandas
import requests
from pandas import DataFrame

from io import StringIO

csv_string = StringIO("""Bot instance,Current,Potential profit,Potential Profit 24h ago,Change last 24h Volume, 24h Volume Market
Biki - TECUSDT,21.69386074 USDT,21.60458081 USDT,0.08927993 USDT,0.84554375 USDT,28577.2565559176490500
Binance - XEMBTC, -3.55974813 BTC,-3.55514961 BTC,-0.00459852 BTC,11.31867593 BTC,924.7716585800000000
Binance - XEM/ETH,-15.38320177 ETH, -15.32533185 ETH,-0.05786992 ETH,35.44241506 ETH,1273.2456803600000000
bitfinex ant/btc, 1.64774952 BTC,1.65615563 BTC,-0.00840611 BTC,0.01056552 BTC,5.2507294117379079
Bitfinex ANT/ETH, -15.93635190 ETH,-15.60342681 ETH,-0.33292509 ETH,0.00000000 ETH,99.3832923859608600""")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data: DataFrame = pandas.read_csv(csv_string)
    response = requests.post(
        'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage',
        data={
            'token': 'your-token',
            'channel': '#the-channel',
            'text': data.to_markdown() # can be what ever you want, ie: data.to_csv()
        }
    )
    print(response.json())
```

*Edit*
[results on slack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBzoO.png)

Comment: Nice idea, would you mind adding a screenshot how this looks like in slack?

Comment: @DimaTisnek added